# Explode a nested pandas dataframe out as columns, and repeat parent rows for each of its row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that's basically akin to something like this:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a': 1,  'b': 2,  'extra': 0},
    {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'extra': 0}
])

df_c1 = pd.io.json.read_json(json.dumps({'row1': {'c1': -1, 'c2': -2}}))

df_c2 = pd.io.json.read_json(json.dumps({
    'row1': {'c1': -10,   'c2': -20},
    'row2': {'c1': -100,  'c2': -200},
    'row3': {'c1': -1000, 'c2': -2000}
}))

df['c'] = [df_c1.T, df_c2.T]
```

I want to get to one that's formatted like this:

ex:

```py
goal = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'row1': {'a': 1,  'b': 2,  'c1': -1,    'c2': -2}}).T,
    pd.DataFrame({'row1': {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c1': -10,   'c2': -20}}).T,
    pd.DataFrame({'row2': {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c1': -100,  'c2': -200}}).T,
    pd.DataFrame({'row3': {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c1': -1000, 'c2': -2000}}).T
])

In [1]: goal
Out[1]:
       a   b    c1    c2
row1   1   2    -1    -2
row1  10  20   -10   -20
row2  10  20  -100  -200
row3  10  20 -1000 -2000

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

A few things to note:

- The index matches that of the corresponding row in the `c` column's data frame
- I only want to include `['a', 'b']`, `'extra'` has been taken out
- The 2nd row in the main `df` has `3` values for `df['c']`, and as such, its `a` and `b` values are repeated 3 times, once for each of the rows in `c`
- If it makes it easier, I can change the line: `df['c'] = [df_c1.T, df_c2.T]` to no longer include the transpose: `df['c'] = [df_c1, df_c2]`, but the source data has to be JSON in the format shown.

My current solution (more or less) is to iterate each element in the original column `'c'`, and then do a join with its parent row while slicing the columns I want to keep. I append this data frame to a list and then do a final `pd.concat` on the list of all the dataframes.

It's slow and disgusting, but it works. I'd love to have some faster and more elegant though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you create a column that every element is a dataframe. But you can use `pandas.concat` and `pandas.merge` to do the job:

```
# your setup code here
df2 = pd.concat(df['c'].tolist(), keys=df.index)
df3 = pd.merge(df[["a", "b"]], df2, left_index=True, right_on=df2.index.get_level_values(0))
df4 = df3.drop("key_0", axis=1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print df4
```

here is the output:

```
       a   b    c1    c2
row1   1   2    -1    -2
row1  10  20   -10   -20
row2  10  20  -100  -200
row3  10  20 -1000 -2000
```

Comment: Also, the reason is because the entire data frame is read in externally but that one column happens to be all JSON. I apply pd.io.json.read_json() to the column but that leaves me with a column of DataFrames that I need to expand out.

Comment: It took some time for me to grab what was done here but a very elegant solution. This answer inspired me to create a function out of this to explode such columns in the data frame which store nested data frames. I am now working on enhancing it accept multiple such columns with nested data frames and explode them in one go.